# Math.floor kind of thing

Tags: javascript, function, math, floor

i found it difficult to search for my question (don't know what keywords to use sorry mods!).

What I want to achieve is something like a Math.floor function but a bit different.

i dont want to floor on decimals but a multitude of 6 for example:

```
var = 1 => return 0
var = 1.1 => return 0
var = 2 => return 0
var = 3 => return 0
var = 4 => return 6
var = 5 => return 6
var = 6 => return 6
var = 7 => return 6
....
var = 13 => return 12
var = 26 => return 24
```

etc.

Thanks in advance for the answer guys!

**Update**: the answer of Grijesh Chauhan works! Thanks m8!

Comment: you want to round down to the closest factor of 6?

Comment: Math.floor(x/6)*6 + (x % 6) > 3 ? 6 : 0

Comment: If you find that an answer solves your problem you should accept the answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of it. This will signal to others that the question has been resolved and award rep points to the author of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have not mention language, do you need this, try this C code:

```
int fun(int n){
   return (n/6)*6;
}
```

**Edit:** For JavaScript:

```
Math.floor(n/6)*6;
```

Comment: language is javascript / jquery

Comment: @FR.Enki for jS do:  `Math.floor(n/6)*6;`

Answer (score 1):

How about modulo-operator?

i = 13;

ans = i - (i % 6)

Edit:
what do you want to achieve? floor or ceil?

Answer (score 0):

I think its something like:

```
Math.floor((x+2)/6)*6;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function round2six(number) {
    return Math.round(number/6)*6;
}
```

Here's a test code:

```
for(i=0; i<20; i++) {
    document.write(i + ' => ');
    document.write(round2six(i));
    document.write('<br/>');
}
```

Result of execution:

```
0 => 0
1 => 0
2 => 0
3 => 6
4 => 6
5 => 6
6 => 6
7 => 6
8 => 6
9 => 12
10 => 12
11 => 12
12 => 12
13 => 12
14 => 12
15 => 18
16 => 18
17 => 18
18 => 18
19 => 18
```